# How to change bundle identifier of rejected app

Tags: xcode, app-store

My app was rejected very first time because of some naming mismatch. 

Now I want to change my `bundle identifier` and submit same version to the app store. When I try to edit the app information section drop-down showing my new `bundle identifier`. But I can't save the new identifier. Apple documentation says **" The bundle identifier cannot be changed if the first version of your app has been approved or if you have enabled Game Center or the `iAd Network`"** .

But my app is not approved yet and have not enabled game center or `iAd network`.  What should I do?

Comment: You just have to create new build with new bundle identifier and upload it. The reason for "But I can't save the new identifier." might be coz you must have not changed the bundle identifier in your xcode before creating the build.

Comment: If you can't change it in iTunes Connect yourself your best bet might be to contact Apple developer support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/559745).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a solution. I have changed my app's name 'MyApp' to 'MyApp1'. That will free the old name and back into the pool for reuse. Then add new app with app name 'MyApp' and delete app 'MyApp1'. In this way we can use new bundle identifier and reuse old app name for rejected apps.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/771644#771644

Comment: Thanks Allen. It worked.. And thanks for the link to official forum..

Answer (score 0):

For changing the app name you can change `Bundle Name` and `Bundle Display Name` in `info plist` file. For changing the `Bundle Identifier` you will have to login in your [developer.apple](https://developer.apple.com/) account then make a new `bundle id` and `Provisioning Profile` then set it in to your app's `info plist` file.

**Edit:** But if your app is already live then you cant change its `Bundle Identifier` for new version of app.

Comment: The first version of my app is rejected. so it is not live yet.

Comment: Then delete this app from iTunes and upload a new binary with changes.

Comment: **Don't delete the application from iTunes Connect.** You can't reuse the name of the application!

Comment: Yes I agree Sorry for that !!

Comment: @TheTiger What if app is not live, it was uploaded to iTunes connect and got rejected with bundle id `com.company.xyz`. After that, I changed it to `com.company.abc`. Now, I want to change it to older one  `com.company.xyz`? I changed it in xcode but when I tried to upload it , it says that bundle ids in project and itunes connect don't match. Even I am not able to change it in itunes connect as it is not availble in drop down list of app ids. Note that it is there in developer.apple.com. Is there any way?